# Independent randomisation of parameters in PsychoPy

Tags: psychopy, experimental-design

I'm building an experiment which requires presentation of two images within a routine, side-by-side. One image is a target (i.e. correct response) and the other is a foil. I have an excel stimuli sheet with all the necessary picture files, target stimuli in one column and foil stimuli in another, however I would like the appearance of foil pictures to be fully random. At present, PsychoPy reads out each row such that the same target image is always paired with the same foil. Is there any way around this? I'm not much of a programmer so I would like to stay within the confines of the builder if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: This can be done, but as PsychoPy is designed to keep rows in conditions files together, in Builder this means inserting a code component to independently shuffle the variables. This can be done in a variety of ways, so suggest you take this question to http://discourse.psychopy.org for the to-and-fro needed to best fit your needs.

Comment: thanks for the tip! yes, I expected I'd need to incorporate a code component. I've taken this to discourse.psychopy as you suggest